# Magento 2 multiple AND/OR conditions

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, collection

I have a collection and I want to filter like this: WHERE field1 >= '2020-01-01' OR (field2 == 'open' && $field3 == 1).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this below way

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
                         array('field1',array(
                                          array('attribute'=>'field2', 'eq' => 'open'), 
                                          array('attribute'=>'field3', 'eq'=>'1')
                                        )
                         ), 
                         array( 
                             array('gteq' => '2020-01-01'),
                         )
                     );
```

Comment: Thank you, Ritesh Santra.